# Do protocol relative URLs affect search crawler behavior, and how?

Tags: http, google-crawlers, protocol-relative

We are working on a web application that will have a preview environment (https) and live which would be (http). Now considering there would be two different schemas involved we have used href for links in HTML page as [protocol-relative URLS](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) as we wanted to use absolute URL for links and we didn't want to bother about HTTP/HTTPS in url.

Now we would like to understand how it would affect search crawler behaviour, if at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be completely fine to use them to serve assets ( Wikipedia uses protocol relative urls.) Using protocol relative URLs within links or canonical URLs, should be avoided.

Comment: we do not have any canonical URLs but we do have some links in header referenced in terms of protocol-relative URLs. Could you elaborate on our answer a little to help understand the repurcussions of this.